# Entity Framework late model checking

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Entity framework does a model check on startup. You can tweak the behavior by implementing a database initializer.

I would like to also check the model against the database schema *later* in the running app - for an easy way to check if all is well for the running application.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I'm asking for Entity Framework 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Database.CompatibleWithModel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.compatiblewithmodel(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Database.CompatibleWithModel(System.Boolean)) method

> Checks whether or not the database is compatible with the the current Code First model.

E.g. something like this

```
YourDbContext db = …;
bool isRecent = db.CompatibleWithModel(true);
```